# materializecss modal in table only get the last row from table when button clicked

Tags: php, mysql, modal-dialog, materialize

So I have a table listing the users, and a button each row to edit in modal. I'm using while loop by the way, but my problem is that it only get the last row every time i click any of the button in the rows. I checked the id's of each row via inspect in browser and they have the right id's. It's just that when i clicked it gives the last row. I'm kind of puzzled because i tried in bootstrap modal and my code is working fine but in materialize css, not.

my loop, inside the loop is the tr and td.

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_user)){


               $account_id          = $row['account_id'];
            $username            = $row['username'];
            $firstname           = $row['firstname'];
            $middlename          = $row['middlename'];
            $lastname            = $row['lastname'];
            $house_number        = $row['house_number'];
            $street_name         = $row['street_name'];
            $provincial_address  = $row['provincial_address'];
            $gender              = $row['gender'];
            $occupation          = $row['occupation'];
            $cel_number          = $row['cel_number'];
            $tel_number          = $row['tel_number'];

            $house_model_name    = $row['house_model_name'];

            $mdues_status        = $row['mdues_status'];
            $account_status_name = $row['account_status_name'];

            $address = '#'. $house_number.' '.$street_name;
            $fullName = $firstname.' '.$middlename[0].'. '.$lastname;
            $fullContact = $cel_number.' , '.$tel_number;
```

}

this is the button

```
 echo "<td><button class='waves-effect waves-light btn update modal-trigger' data-toggle='modal'  data-target='billingModal' id='{$account_id}' style='margin: 5px; background-color: #6E6702;'><i class='material-icons left'>create</i>Edit</button></td>";
```

this is the modal

```
<div id="billingModal" class="modal" role="dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <h5><?php echo $account_id?></h5> <!--Name of home owner-->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p><?php echo $address?><br> <!--Address of home owner-->
        09152462389</p><!--Contact Number of home owner-->
      </div> <!--TABLE FOR BILL-->
      <!-- <input type="input" id="id"> -->

      <div style="margin: 20px;">
        <div class="row">
          <h5><span style"background-color: #B7AFAF;">Billing Summary</span></h5>
          <div class="divider"></div>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn" style="margin: 5px; background-color: #B7AFAF;">Close</a>
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn" style="margin: 5px; background-color: #B7AFAF;">Print</a>
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn" style="margin: 5px; background-color: #108DC9;">Pay</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i tried also doing like this in button

```
 echo "<td><button class='waves-effect waves-light btn update modal-trigger' data-toggle='modal'  href=#billingModal$account_id;' style='margin: 5px; background-color: #6E6702;'><i class='material-icons left'>create</i>Edit</button></td>";
```

and in modal

```
<div id="billingModal<?php echo $account_id; ?>" class="modal" role="dialog">
```